# Is there a way to detect file move operation from a visual studio add in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins

I am writing a visual studio add-in which preforms operations on javascript files after they have been added, removed, renamed and moved. The first 3 events are exposed by ProjectItemsEvents class, along he lines of:

```
this._applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
this._addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

this.events = _applicationObject.Events as Events2;
this.projectItemsEvents = events.ProjectItemsEvents;
this.projectItemsEvents.ItemRenamed += ProjectItemRenamed;
```

However, there does not appear to be a way to detect when a file is moved, for instance between solution folders. Performing such an operation does even not appear to result in an ItemRemoved and ItemAdded event as I might expect.

Does anybody know how I should go about detecting the file moved event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor the solution's directory yourself. When moving  a file, it should fire a [Deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted.aspx) event followed by a [Created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event.

Comment: This won't work completely here.  A project item in Visual Studio doesn't necessarily have a real backing file.  It could be an in-memory / designer generated item

Comment: @JaredPar The OP mentioned js files so I think these are physical files.

Answer (score 3):

After digging some time on this I found a suitable way to detect file move actions.

You should first subscribe to item change events for projects inside a solution in your [Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) code by implementing [IVsSolutionEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), use [IVsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.advisesolutionevents%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and listen to [OnAfterOpenProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafteropenproject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You should also implement [IVsHierarchyEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchyevents%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and subscribe to e.g. OnItemAdded and OnItemDeleted events by calling [IVsHierarchy.AdviseHierarchyEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.advisehierarchyevents%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). File moves can be detected by subsequent occurence of OnItemAdded and OnItemDeleted:

```
public class MyVsHierarchyEvents : IVsHierarchyEvents
{
   public int OnItemAdded( uint itemidParent, uint itemidSiblingPrev, uint itemidAdded )
   {
      object itemAddedExtObject;
      if ( m_hierarchy.GetProperty( itemidAdded, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out itemAddedExtObject ) == VSConstants.S_OK )
      {
         var projectItem = itemAddedExtObject as ProjectItem;
         if ( projectItem != null )
         {
            // do something here ...
         }
      }
      return VSConstants.S_OK;
   }

   public int OnItemDeleted( uint itemid )
   {
      object itemExtObject;
      if ( m_hierarchy.GetProperty( itemid, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out itemExtObject ) == VSConstants.S_OK )
      {
         var projectItem = itemExtObject as ProjectItem;
         if (projectItem != null)
          {
             // do something here ...
          }
      }
      return ret;
   }
   // handle other events ...
}
public class MySolutionEvents : IVsSolutionEvents
{
   IVsHierarchyEvents m_myVsHierarchyEvents;
   uint m_cookie;
   public int OnAfterOpenProject( IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, int fAdded )
   {
       m_myVsHierarchyEvents = new MyVsHierarchyEvents();
       pHierarchy.AdviseHierarchyEvents( m_myVsHierarchyEvents, out m_cookie );
       // do other things here ...
       return VSConstants.S_OK;
   }
   // handle other events ...
}
public class MyPackage : Package
{
   IVsSolutionEvents m_vsSolutionEvents;
   IVsSolution m_vsSolution;
   uint m_SolutionEventsCookie;
   protected override void Initialize()
   {
      m_vsSolutionEvents = new MySolutionEvents();
      m_vsSolution = GetService( typeof( SVsSolution ) ) as IVsSolution;
      m_vsSolution.AdviseSolutionEvents( m_vsSolutionEvents, out m_SolutionEventsCookie );
   }
}
```

**NOTE:**

I also created a detector using FileSystemWatcher, as vc 74 suggested. However, it was somehow tricky to figure out suitable patterns of Create / Change / Delete events because different ones exist at least in in VS 2010 professional that occur after a file is moved inside a project. From my observation for the file becoming moved the create event is triggered first, followed by two change events, and finally a delete event. But, I also observed that sometimes there occurs another update event for the destination directory at different times.